# MySQL Error 2006 (HY000) at line 406: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: mysql

I have a MYSQL dump from a database that I am trying to move to a new db server. When I try to import my sql dump, I receive the following error:

```
MySQL Error 2006 (HY000) at line 406: MySQL server has gone away
```

I googled the problem and most people fixed the problem by changing the value of wait_timeout. However, my current value is set to 28800 (8 hours) and the error appears in less than 8 seconds when I run the import.

I also tried setting the value of max_allowed_packet to 1073741824 but that also did not fix the problem.

Looking through the mysql dump, there are quite a few blob columns in the dump, but the overall file size is only 6 MB.

Does anyone have any ideas about what else might be the problem?

Comment: As a workaround, I went back to the source database server and make several smaller dump files (5 tables at a time). Then, I imported each of the smaller dump files and this let me accomplish my database transfer without the error message.

Answer (score 48):

Adding this answer for the benefit of future searchers, as it explains why increasing the packet size fixed the problem:

> The situation is that if a client sends a SQL-statement longer than the server max_allowed_packet setting, the server will simply disconnect the client. Next query from the same client instance will find that the ‘MySQL server has gone away’.
>
> ... But it would of course be much preferable to have the ‘got packet bigger’ error [Error: 2020 (CR_NET_PACKET_TOO_LARGE)] returned if that is the problem.

*Excerpted from and thanks for [peter_laursen's blog post](http://www.webyog.com/blog/2009/08/10/mysql-server-has-gone-away-part-1-max_allowed_packet/)*

On OSX 10.7 (Lion), I created a file, /etc/my.cnf with the following contents:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 12000000
```

And then stopped the mysql server:

```
/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop
```

When it automatically restarted I was able to execute my inserts.

Comment: Well I got the same problem even for max_allowed_packet = 512M

Comment: @AbhijitBuchake - then it's likely not a 'packet too large' problem, but some other reason for the disconnect.  Unfortunately, I don't have any other suggestions for you.

Comment: THANK YOU! I have read and tried over a dozen scenarios. I have re-installed mysql 3 times. The above trick for the my.cnf fix it. I was trying to add a 50m mysql database into mysql through command line. That totally made my day!

Answer (score 6):

Increasing max_allowed_packet to 12 MB (12000000) solved the problem for me when trying to import a 130 MB file.

Change the ini file or under Options File / Networking in MySQL Workbench (MySQL restart required).

If you still get the error, try increasing even more (100 MB). Just remember to decrease it when you're done.

Answer (score 0):

1) Change in MySql config file:
    #
    /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
#section 
#
[mysqld]
#
key_buffer              = 32M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 512K
thread_cache_size       = 64
#
```

2) MySql deamon restart

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

Should resolve yours issues.