# Repeated SQL Error: 2006: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I have a recurring issue with a CakePHP application. On a daily basis the error logs are showing

> `SQL Error: 2006: MySQL server has gone away`  in [/home/t553788/public_html/res360/res/cake/libs/model/datasources/dbo_source.php.

I have contacted my hosting company and the MySQL server timeout value has been increased but this hasn't prevented the error from occurring.

Has anybody any idea as to what else may be causing this and also how would I go about presenting a custom error to the user when this happens?

Comment: I assume your mysql server is not on the same machine? from your server, what is the average ping length? Is it on a virtual dedicated server? whats your average traffic look like? highest traffic? Just wondering from the aspect of connectivity and the possible reasons of your Denial of Service.

Comment: Related: [MySQL Error 2006 (HY000) at line 406: MySQL server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744813/mysql-error-2006-hy000-at-line-406-mysql-server-has-gone-away) - It has some more answers, there can be many reasons for the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 12):

You should try changing in my.cnf/my.ini these variables and see if it helps.

`[mysqld]`

max_allowed_packet=12M

wait_timeout=28800

Comment: All I needed to change was `max_allowed_packet`. The default was `1M`, increasing to `10M` made all the difference