# MySQL server has gone away exception while importing a huge database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, import

I am trying to import a new database from an sql dump file with size above 2.6 GB. To do this I am running the below command to import the database from the sql file.

```
mysql -u root -proot --database=test_db < test_db.sql
```

and the error response I got at this time.

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 51: MySQL server has gone away
```

I think the problem over here is some timeout is happening somewhere. Only one table has creatd in the new database from the sql file. Is there anyway to overcome this issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744813/mysql-error-2006-hy000-at-line-406-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the `max_allowed_packet` setting to a larger value in the server.

Open `"my.ini/cnf"`, located in your `MySQL` installation folder, and under `[mysqld]` section change `"max_allowed_packet = 64M"` and don't forget to restart the server. You can check the value by executing:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
```

Refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html